# How to bind an absolute path using data-ng-src in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Hi Um using angular for the first time to bind data to an img tag

Um using

```
<img data-ng-src="{{img.filePath}}" alt="{{img.vehicleId}}" style="width:10%" />
```

to show an image and the value of img.filePath as follows but it wont show up

```
 D:\Country\Province\City\Images\A0001\2676199\aaaaaaaa-5a59-4bfb-b1ba-0faff297b7b1.jpg
```

There are no compile errors or any  other errors in the code.   Image is available in correct path.

Why is it not working ? Thank you in advance

Comment: The image src should be an **http** URL. Not the path of a file on your drive. The browser won't let a web page open images on the client machine. And if it did, the url should look like `file://D:/Country...`

Comment: @JBNizet Hi , you mean data-ng-src should be a browser URL?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "a browser URL". The src should look like `http://some.host/some/image.jpg`.

Comment: Thank you that is what I have  meant by a browser url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your index.html(main html from where you load all your js)  track that file location.

if your index.html is in "D:\Country\"

then in ng-src ="Province/City/ImagesA0001/2676199/aaaaaaaa-5a59-4bfb-b1ba-0faff297b7b1.jpg"

Comment: Right. I Just copied his location from that file path.